# Give a regular expression for $A = \{1^{k}y|k \geq 1, y \in \{0,1\}^{*}$ and $y$ contains at least $k$ $1$'s $\}$

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, regular-expressions

The regular expression that is given is $1(0 \cup 1)^{*}10^{*}$. I'm having trouble realizing why this regular expression describes the language given. For example, the string (for $k$ = 4) $1111$ $1111$ $01101010$ is in the language, but I don't see how this can be derived from the regular expression. In particular, the part that says there are at least $k$ $1$'s doesn't seem to be satisfied in the regular expression. Any clarifications will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of $A$ is misleading. There is no reason to ever have $k>1$. Think of it as $$A=\{1y|y\in\{0,1\}^\star\textrm{ and }y\textrm{ contains  at least one }1\}$$

---

The question from the commments is why does the regular expression equal this.  There are many ways to express a string that contains at least one 1.  $(0\cup 1)^\star10^\star$ is one such way; the mandatory 1 is of necessity the last 1 in the string, since it is followed only by zeroes.  Another, more natural way, is $(0\cup 1)^\star 1 (0\cup 1)^\star$.  Another way is $0^\star 1 (0\cup 1)^\star$; now the mandatory 1 is the first 1 in the string.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm having trouble understanding why the $k$ is unnecessary.

Comment: Because if $11y\in A$, then set $y'=1y$, and $1y'\in A$.

Comment: So in the regular expression, why does the $1$ after the first $1$ go where it does? It seems like it could go in any other spot and still represent the same strings.

Comment: Where does the $0^*$ come from? I can understand the $(0 \cup 1)^* 1$, but I don't see how we get the $0^*$ at the end.

Comment: You get 0* at the end because otherwise the very last symbol would have to be 1.

Comment: Why is that wrong? If we have $1y$ it seems like we should get the regular expression $1 (0 \cup 1)^* 1$ where the 1 denotes the 1 in $1y$ and $(0 \cup 1)^* 1$ denotes $y$. I'm just confused how $0^*$ makes sense, because y is defined to be $\in \{0,1\}^*$

Comment: Because you want the language to include $1010$, where $y=010$.